# What is the optimal solution for hosting multiple applications using droplets at digital ocean?

Tags: digital-ocean

The applications each has their own data and meanwhile shares some data. Some app files are shared as well. Some applications are big (many files and being visited often by many requests) and some are small. Considering both speed and security for evaluation, I can think of following options:

(1) one droplet for each application and all its data;
(2) one droplet for each application and its own data and one droplet for all shared data;
(3) one droplet for each application and one droplet for all data (each app's own data and shared data).
(4) all apps and data in one droplet.